# Prestashop New Installation BUGS

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have installed prestashop 1.6.x on my web server. I haven't changed or updated anything and already got 3 errors in Back-End(Admin) Panel and 1 in Front End.

```
Warning on line 551 in file C:\xampp\htdocs\Shop\classes\controller\AdminController.php
[2] count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Unknown error on line 1554 in file C:\xampp\htdocs\Shop\classes\module\Module.php
[8192] Function create_function() is deprecated

Warning on line 56 in file C:\xampp\htdocs\Shop\cache\smarty\compile\60\ab\3e\60ab3e4bf24b64cb2326ddb2ae8fbf6550240224.file.js.tpl.php
[2] count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

And in Front Panel

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\Shop\modules\blockcart\blockcart.php on line 158
```

Where could I found problem? Or is this some bug and I need to install different version?

Comment: Yes you need to install different PHP version. Because PrestaShop like many other older apps isn't compatible with PHP 7.2

Comment: @TheDrot Thanks, now working. Please make it as answer :)